# ADFv2 is on Copy Activity giving out Error "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream", Any Idea?

Tags: azure

We have source side Self Hosted IR which is connected to a Windows 2012 R2 server, and sink side Azure Blob storage container. Both connections are tested and working fine. But, when we trigger the copy activity it's running for about 20 mins and failing after that with the following error:

```
 {
        "errorCode": "2200",
        "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToCreateAzureBlobContainer,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Unable to create Azure Blob container. Endpoint: https://blobthinkrisk.blob.core.windows.net/, Container Name: am01.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.,Source=System,''Type=System.IO.IOException,Message=Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.,Source=System,'",
        "failureType": "UserError",
        "target": "Extractor",
        "details": []
    }
```

Any idea what might be the reason and how to fix this issue?

I have both read/write privileges in azure blob, and I can preview the source data using ADF source connection. But why I'm not able to write it to the blob as a CSV file?

[source_LS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCSga.png)

[sink_LS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY3fL.png)

[copy_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHSLO.png)